# Terraform variables getting "cached" when executing terraform plan

Tags: terraform

I have the following problem. Suppose I have this setup:

**Main.tf**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_security_group" {
  name        = var.security_group_name
  ...
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "security_group_name" {
    type = string
}
```

**my_var_file.tfvars**

```
security_group_name = "foo"
```

And I have a backend that points to an AWS S3 bucket.

I applied this some time ago, it generated a tfplan file and `.tfstate` files. Now I want to change the name of the security group (among other things) so my `.tfvars` file looks like this

```
security_group_name = "bar"
```

If I execute the following:

```
$ terraform init
$ terraform plan -var-file="my_var_file.tfvars" -out "tfplan.out"
```

I notice that the plan includes creating a security group with name "foo" instead of "bar", like it's not paying attention to the updated value in the var file:

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.
aws_security_group.vpc_security_group: Refreshing state... [id=foo:terraform-20201014191031939100000001]
```

Is there something I need to include in the `plan` command to have it ignore previous plans?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the output from `terraform plan`? There's not anything you need to include to make `plan` ignore previous plans so I'd like to confirm that the output is actually saying it's going to create the sg with `foo` again.

Comment: @theonlyrao I updated the post with that information

Comment: My guess is your not passing that variable around between your resources correctly. It's hard to tell from what you've posted though. Follow the variable though your code carefully and ensure it's passed as you expect it to be. I gues it could also be a bug, ensure your using the latest version of TF and the AWS provider

Comment: If all of that is true I'd file a bug with the AWS provider on github. I find bugs in Terraform almost weekly. For example this [open bug I have](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8745) isn't that dissimilar to what your seeing here, though obviously a totally different provider, etc

Comment: @Heathcliff there should be more output from `terraform plan` that what you've posted. If what you have pasted is *all* of the output then there's some issue with your ability to connect to your AWS account. Perhaps you need to open a VPN tunnel or update/refresh your AWS credentials. The output you posted is just terraform saying it has found the old 'foo' security group in your state file and is querying AWS to determine what is currently going on with that security group before determining what changes you have made.